# Some questions regarding decidability and semi-decidability of $A/B = \{ w \text{ | }\exists z \in B, wz \in A\}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, semi-decidability

I have found two interesting questions regarding the quotient of languages, described as:

$A/B = \{ w \text{ | }\exists z \in B, wz \in A\}$

The first one is:

- Let $A$ and $B$ be regular languages, prove that $A/B$ is decidable

By using the proof from [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13771/quotient-of-a-regular-language), it can be proved that $A/B$ is regular if $A$ is regular too.

Then, since any regular language is decidable, $A/B$ will be regular (and decidable) too.

The second one is:

- Let $A$ and $B$ be decidable languages, prove that $A/B$ is semi-decidable

I have no idea on how to prove this one, I assume that it's somehow related to $A$ and $B$ being able to stop for any string, whether it's accepted or rejected, but since I don't know whether $A$ is regular or not, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Sigma$ be your alphabet. You want to design a Turing machine $T$ such that, given any word $w \in \Sigma^*$, $T(w)$ accepts if and only if $w \in A / B$. Notice that since you only want to prove that $A/B$ is semi-decidable, $T(w)$ is not required to reject when $w \not\in A / B$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are decidable, you know that there are two Turing machines $T_A$ and $T_B$ such that that $T_A(x)$ (resp. $T_B(x)$) accepts if $x \in A$ (resp. $x \in B$) and rejects otherwise.

You can then design $T$ as follows:

- For each word $z \in \Sigma^*$:

  - If $T_B(z)$ accepts and $T_A(wz)$ accepts:

    - Accept.

Comment: Oh! I see. That was simple...thank you.